# JSON data shown on viewDidAppear and not viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have this that download the JSON and I have appended them into an array

```
    func downloadDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete){
    Alamofire.request(API_URL).responseJSON { (response) in
        let result = response.result
        let json = JSON(result.value!).array
        let jsonCount = json?.count
        let count = jsonCount!

        for i in 0..<(count){
            let image = json![i]["urls"]["raw"].stringValue
            self.imagesArray.append(image)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(self.imagesArray)

        completed()
    }
}
```

I know that `viewDidLoad` loads first and `viewDidAppear` load later. I am trying to retrieve the array that contain all the informations but it's not showing on `viewDidLoad` as the array is empty but its showing on `viewDidAppear` with an array of ten and I dont know how to get that from `viewDidAppear`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var imageList: Image!
var imagesArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad " ,imagesArray)
    setupDelegate()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    downloadDetails {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        }
        print("viewDidAppear ", self.imagesArray)
    }
}
```

The output is as follow

```
viewDidLoad  []

viewDidAppear  ["https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464550883968-cec281c19761", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464550838636-1a3496df938b", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464550580740-b3f73fd373cb", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464547323744-4edd0cd0c746", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464545022782-925ec69295ef", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464537356976-89e35dfa63ee", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464536564416-b73260a9532b", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464536194743-0c49f0766ef6", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464519586905-a8c004d307cc", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464519046765-f6d70b82a0df"]
```

What is the right way to access the array with information in it?

Comment: You call downloadDetails() in viewDidAppear function. Move it to the viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

that's because the request is asynchronous it's not getting executed as serial lines of code , there should be a delay according to network status , besides you don't even call `downloadDetails` inside `viewDidLoad`

//

you also need to reload table here

```
downloadDetails {  // Alamofire callback by default runs in main queue
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your method on

```
viewDidLoad()
```

And maybe you should learn more about iOS lifecycle, so you can spot the difference between **viewDidLoad** and **viewDidAppear**